# Spark DataFrame from SequenceFile

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, sequencefile

```
sqlContext.read.format('orc').load(hdfspath)
sqlContext.read.format('parquet').load(hdfspath)
```

This works fine

```
sqlContext.read.format('sequencefile').load(hdfspath)
```

But sequencefile format does not work like that.

How can I read a sequence file as a dataframe in PySpark?

Comment: No, https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007 is about a particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sequenceFile` method from **SparkContext**:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name 

df = sc.sequenceFile("/tmp/foo/").toDF()
```

Comment: I think import statement is not required.